# How to add NotBlank validation in frontend for FosUserBundle login form

Tags: php, forms, security, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using FOSUserBundle to manager the users on my site. For authentication, I have implemented the form login and configured it in `'security.yml'` :

```
form_login:
   provider: fos_userbundle
   csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
   default_target_path: /
```

It is working, but I want to first check if the `"_username"` and the `"_password"` fields are not empty, because at the moment, I always get the error: "Invalid username or password" - even if no data has been entered in the form. So it would be nicer to first check if the two fields are not blank. How can this be accomplished ?

Comment: Edit your template and use JS or HTML5 validation

Comment: You can use [this](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md) as a starter to override FOSUserBundle templates and add your own JS or HTML validation

Comment: I also thought of using plain js validation for that, so as i read now on a few sites, it's not possible to "hook into the pre-authentication" mechanism of FOSUserBundle login .

Comment: *Symfony form login in general was what i meant.